# Python: Having trouble breaking a loop inside a thread using global variables

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-multithreading

So I am really new to threading...I am trying to use a global variable to break a loop inside a thread but for some reason the thread doesn't seem to understand that I have changed the global variable. Here is my code...any help is much appreciated. :)

```
import threading

keepThreadRunning = True

def myThreadFunc():
    while keepThreadRunning:
        print keepThreadRunning
    return

myThread = threading.Thread(target = myThreadFunc())
myThread.start()
keepThreadRunning = False
myThread.join()
```

Comment: You need to fix your thread instantiation: you want `target = myThreadFunc` (no parentheses), not `target = myThreadFunc()`. As it is, you're running `myThreadFunc` in the *main* thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it never stops is that the code never reaches the point where the flag is unset.

```
myThread = threading.Thread(target = myThreadFunc())
```

You are executing the function immediately in the main thread. It will block until that function exits and since nothing can set `keepThreadRunning` to `False` it never exits.

Instead you should pass a reference to the function.

```
myThread = threading.Thread(target = myThreadFunc)
```

It will then be correctly executed in the new thread.

Comment: It's honestly one of the most common mistakes seen on this site.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it solves your issue.